# error code WFP: State Error (active) E0513 a value of type "const wchar_t *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "wchar_t *"

Tags: c++, wfp

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019, SDK & WDK preview.

> E0513 a value of type "const wchar_t *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "wchar_t *".

How to fix it?

```
SubLayer.displayData.name = L"APPDinsFirewall";
SubLayer.displayData.description = L"APPDinsFirewall";
```

Code WFP below:

```
DWORD AppFilter::appBindInterface() {

    DWORD ErrorCode = ERROR_BAD_COMMAND;
    //RPC - Remote Procedure Call status Gọi hàm thủ tục từ xa
    RPC_STATUS rpcStatus = {0};
    //Sublayer structure
    //FWPM_SUBLAYER0 SubLayer = {0};
    FWPM_SUBLAYER0 SubLayer;
    memset(&SubLayer, 0, sizeof(SubLayer));
    //Tạo một GUID cho SubLayer
    rpcStatus = UuidCreate(&SubLayer.subLayerKey);
    if (rpcStatus == NO_ERROR) {
        /* Lưu GUID để sử dụng sau này. 
        Sao chép bộ nhớ từ SubLayer sang appsubGUID từ size của subLayerKey
        */
        CopyMemory(&appsubGUID, &SubLayer.subLayerKey, sizeof(SubLayer.subLayerKey));
        //Gán thông tin trong SubLayer
        SubLayer.displayData.name = APP_SUBLAYER_NAMEW;
        SubLayer.displayData.description = APP_SUBLAYER_NAMEW;
        SubLayer.flags = 0;
        SubLayer.weight = 0x100;
        //Add SubLayer
        ErrorCode = FwpmSubLayerAdd0(appEngineHandle, &SubLayer, NULL);
    }
    return ErrorCode;
}
```

> E0513 a value of type "const wchar_t *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "wchar_t *"

Comment: Just a note: I would recommend keeping all code, comments and VCS history in English. Even for throwaway projects, even for something that only makes sense in your country. You never know who you might want to ask for help or who gets to work on it later. I'm sure you yourself would not want to deal with a program that is commented in (insert language from the other end of the world) ;-P

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that the other code won't write into it, you can cast the constness away with `const_cast<wchar_t *>(APP_SUBLAYER_NAMEW)`, if the code does write into it later, your program will crash.

Or you could make a writable duplicate of the string with something like `_wcsdup`, you should also not forget to deallocate it later.

Or you could store the string in a `wchar_t` array in global or static scope. Not a local variable, that would crash in interesting ways as well.

Comment: If "the other code" don't write to the strings, they should have been declared `const  wchar_t *` rather than `wchar_t *`.  `const_cast` is better reserved for those cases when you know better than the compiler what is going on.  And typically you don't :-)

Comment: @HAL9000 or to deal with broken APIs which might actually be this case.